# Reduce duplicates of nodes with hierarchical taxonomy in views

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-views

Drupal 6.15
Views 6.x-2.10

I want to list all of the nodes with a view and want to display their taxonomy in a certain vocabulary. The nodes are organised in hierarchical mode.

When I list the nodes, the nodes in a subcategory are listed twice, once with the term and once with the parent term.

I've tried listing the terms both with Taxonomy: Term and Taxonomy: All Terms, the duplicates are there in both cases. The only difference is that Taxonomy: All Terms lists both the term and parent term on both entries in the list.

Is there any way of displaying these results without the duplicates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you read http://drupal.org/node/770782? For starters, you may want to change your view from a 'node' to a 'taxonomy' view, then bring in any other fields you want with a Relationship.

This approach should solve most isues with duplicates in taxonomy views.

Comment: It was actually way simpler than that. Enabling distinct in the general options for the display solved the problem. Wonder why I didn't try that first thing.